# Not able to register/add EC2 instance to Load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I have created a Cluster using ECS to which I have added one running EC2 instance.
Now I want to add that instance to Load Balancer (Classic Load balancing). 
But, when I go to 'Edit instances' option in Load Balancer, no instance is listed there.

My EC2 instance, ECS cluster, Load Balancer all are in same region.

Is there any other configuration need to be done?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add a policy under permissions and check administrator access.

Answer (score 0):

ECS is special. You can add instances to an ELB, but the problem with ECS is that the AWS Docker agent is what contains the info for you. To tie a  task definition to an ELB you must create a service. A service contains more metadata on top of the task definition including what ELB to put it under.